# Sync SharePoint Calendar Overlays in Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sync, sharepoint-calendar

I created a SharePoint calendar with several other calendars overlaying it.  I want to sync the calendar and the overlays together, as one calendar, to Outlook.  I can sync the main calendar and each of the overlay calendars, individually.  But I want to get them as one.  How is this done?
Thanks!

Comment: Sharepoint may have made changes since this post, but I am having the opposite problem. I have created a color coded calendar with different categories and created different overlays/views so that they will all display. When I connect the calendar to Outlook, all categories show. Is there a way to sync only one view. EX: I have several categories including, "Holidays." I only want Holidays to show up in Outlook, but all categories show.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/80873)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. They have to be overlayed individually through Outlook, and overlayed in Outlook. SharePoint overlay just brings them together for viewing purposes, and so does Outlook. There is no way to bring them all together, unless you want to combine them permanently.

When you connect to all the calendars individually, you can checkbox all of the calendars you want to overlay and the title of the calendar will have a <- arrow that you can click and it will put the calendars in "Overlay Mode"

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I was hopeful that there was a step or a button I missed to get the job done. Back to basics, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility if you don't mind doing some workflows in SharePoint Designer, is to just have all the appointments from each calendar copied over into one master calendar.  I do that on my site, and it's very helpfu.  All of our project managers add their big projects on their own calendar in SP, then they are all individually copied over to the Master Project calendar.  You can then sync that master calendar to Outlook.  Would that work/help?